# GridView full screen, but only cells without headers, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, fullscreen

I need to fill my screen with grid which will be certain size. I don't need headers just cells.
I know I can use datagridview in c# but I don't know how to use it correctly.

I need some example for filling full screen with grid, without headers and with possibility of changing height and width of cell.

And is it possible to go trought the cells like cell[9,4], for example.

When form loads I will measure widht and height of the screen and fill it with cells.

Thank you

Comment: ASP.NET? WinForms? ASP.NET MVC? WCF?

Comment: And... what have you tried yourself?

Comment: I am digging trough the properties..Which come in VS, but nothing to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Docking`of the `DataGridView` to `Fill` 
Then set the `ColumnHeadersVisible` to `False` and do the same with `RowHeadersVisible`(in the `Appearance`group)

That should give you a DataGridView that has the full size of its container, and without visible headers.

Programmaticaly this would give you :

```
DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False
DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = False
DataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```